# Name of font by powershell

Tags: powershell, fonts, truetype

I'm trying to write a Poweshell script that installs all fonts (in formats `.ttf` and `.otf`) from a given directory. However I want to ignore fonts that are already installed. For that purpose I need to get the names (**not the filenames**) of the fonts.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED from comments from @LotPings

You can use .NET for that. In the following example you go through the list of files in a given path, then use the class PrivateFontCollection to retrieve the font names.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$path = "<path to the fonts>\*.ttf"

$ttfFiles = Get-ChildItem $path

$fontCollection = new-object System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection

$ttfFiles | ForEach-Object {
    $fontCollection.AddFontFile($_.fullname)
    $fontCollection.Families[-1].Name
}
```

Comment: You need to `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing` and `$fontCollection.Families[0].Name` will repeat the first font, change to `[-1]`

Comment: @LotPings Thanks. Will it install the missing fonts as well?

Comment: No this does not install the fonts, it just finds the names

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided by Micky Balladelli, the following code add the functionality to rename the ".ttf" files with their font names:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$path = ".\*.ttf"

$ttfFiles = Get-ChildItem $path

$fontCollection = new-object System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection

$ttfFiles | ForEach-Object {
    # Add the font file to the collection to extract its name
    $fontCollection.AddFontFile($_.FullName)
    $fontName = $fontCollection.Families[-1].Name

    # Generate a valid file name from the font name
    $safeFontName = $fontName -replace "[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]", ""
    $newFileName = "$safeFontName.ttf"

    # Full path for the new file
    $newFilePath = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath $newFileName

    # Rename the file, checking if the new file name already exists
    if (-not (Test-Path $newFilePath)) {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newFileName
        Write-Host "Renamed $($_.Name) to $newFileName"
    } else {
        Write-Warning "A file named $newFileName already exists. Skipping $_."
    }
}

# Dispose the font collection after processing
$fontCollection.Dispose()
```

Just copy paste the above code to PowerShell to run. It seems there is a problem with the code is that sometimes it claims there a file already exists with the same name when there is not. When it happens you just run the whole code multiple times.